# Magento redirect from all pages if not logged in

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, custom, login

So, I need to redirect user to some page(tt can be CMS or customer/account) if he did not logged. And on this page(CMS or customer/account) I will have a form to login/register. So, I made an observer for `controller_action_predispatch` event and method which will be implemented it,  I did:

```
public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
        }
    }
```

But I have a problem, I cannot get to this page, because it infinitely redirect me. Any advices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting the infinite loop, because when you redirect to `Mage::getUrl('customer/account')` your observer is called again and redirects you to the same page.
You need to add a rule for when the redirect is not made.
Something like this.

```
public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());
    $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
    $openActions = array(
        'create',
        'createpost',
        'login',
        'loginpost',
        'logoutsuccess',
        'forgotpassword',
        'forgotpasswordpost',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'confirm',
        'confirmation'
    );
    if ($controller == 'account' && in_array($action, $openActions)) {
         return $this; //if in allowed actions do nothing.
    }
    if(! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did, but it also redirect infinitely..

Comment: @sergio. Like I said, the code is not tested. Is just an idea. You can debug the code above to see why you get the second redirect.

Comment: @sergio. Ok I tested the code. There was an error in my method. I fixed it now. See my answer update. It works fine for me.

Comment: Hm, probably I did not understand something, but I copy code, and it also reload infinitely(magento is clear(new))

Comment: @sergio Clear the cache. And make sure you copy the full method. I changed the redirect page from `customer/account` to `customer/account/login`.

Answer (score 3):

## An improved solution:

- redirect for every route except "customer". This will not interfer with login, create account, password reset... and other customer actions already redirect to the login anyway.
- set the `no-dispatch` flag. This is important because otherwise the action is executed and the page rendered even though it will not be shown to the user
- use `Mage_Customer_Model_Session::authenticate()` to check the login and redirect. This will also save the currently requested URL in the session and redirect back after login

### Code:

```
public function redirectNotLogged(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    if ($controller->getRouteName() === 'customer') {
        return;
    }
    if (! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($controller)) {
        $controller->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
    }
}
```

If you want to use a custom login page instead of `customer/account/login`, you can pass this custom URL as second parameter to `authenticate()`, but you also have to check for this action additionally to not get an infinite redirect loop again:

```
if ($controller->getFullActionName() === 'your_custom_page') {
    return;
}
```

and

```
authenticate($controller, Mage::getUrl('your/custom/page'))
```