# Password Access by storeview and different price

Tags: price, store-view

i have few store-view, i want for my second Exclusive store-view add access with password, and then add different price by products

Let me know how i can do better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/15889/146) how to restrict access to not logged in customers for the whole website.

You need to modify that so it will be called only for your desired website. Wrap everything in

```
if(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() == 'your website id here')
```

And for product prices, change the price attribute scope to 'website' from `System->Configuration->Catalog->Price` and then you can just edit the product on a particular store view (from your `Exclusive`website`) and set a different price.

This won't work with different store views under the same website. You need to have a different website.

Comment: Thanks, which file should I modify? can tell me?

Comment: The `redirectNotLogged` you should create. It is explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: wich folder? can tell? because i can not found which i can created file

Comment: @JohnGenry. [Read this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method). It should teach you how to create an observer in Magento.

Comment: Marius, without observer possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. Most probably you can rewrite a class or something, but it's cleaner with an observer.