# Magento 2: How to set module wise login permission access?

Tags: magento2, login, customer-account, permissions

I have below files

```
\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\MyModule\NewAction.php
\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\MyModule\Edit.php
\app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\MyModule\Form.php
```

I would like to set module wise login permission.

If user is logged in then only they are able to access above pages otherwise redirected to homepage.

I have below code to check, but i have to put in each & every file.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
    $customerSession->getCustomerId();
    $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
    $customerSession->getCustomer();
    $customerSession->getCustomerData();
    $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
}
```

Can we manage this login permission through XML file or any better way?

Comment: I think we should use `controller_action_predispatch`. Read more: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/magento-2-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-if-not-logged-in/131713#131713

Comment: We can't set on XML file level? Like this File path will be called after login only? So we have to just define file path or module

Comment: P.S. Never use the `ObjectManager` directly, use Dependency Injection in your controller to get the objects you need. See my answer...

Comment: @MikeSmith we should check the login permission all time. So, we can use the observer event.

Comment: @7ochem I didn't get not directly use `ObjectManager`. Suppose in one file Block/Controller/Any file. If i will use more than 1 `ObjectManager` then what will be effect? Speed? Please explain the right solution. Not Clear to me

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *Request Validator*.

Your Request Validator is a class that is validating the request and returns a controller result. The magic happens at `!$this->session->isLoggedIn()`:

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Action;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class RequestValidator
{
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @param ResultFactory $resultFactory
     * @param Session $session
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResultFactory $resultFactory,
        Session $session
    ) {
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * Get validator result
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect|null
     */
    public function getResult(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $result = null;
        if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            /** @var $result \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect */
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setRefererUrl();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

On top of every one of your controller's `execute()` methods you add a call to the request validator's `getResult()` method:

```
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\MyModule;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Custom\Module\Model\Action\RequestValidator;

class NewAction extends Action
{

    protected $requestValidator;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param RequestValidator $requestValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RequestValidator $requestValidator
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->requestValidator = $requestValidator;
    }

    // ...

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->requestValidator->getResult($this->getRequest());
        if ($result) {
            // There is a result, which means the customer is not logged in
            return $result;
        }

        // ... Do the stuff when customer is logged in ...
    }

    // ...
}
```