# Magento2 : Redirect Page From Observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect

I want to restrict some unwanted users to access the site. So I am redirecting them to 404 Page but my logic is going to an **infinite loop** as the event I am calling from `controller_action_predispatch` is called **several times** and I am not able to find the right one.

My Logic

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

class RedirectUsers implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {

    protected $_myHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Namespace\Module\Helper\Data $myHelper,
    ) {
        $this->_myHelper = $myHelper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        if(in_array($currentUser, $restrictedUsers)){
            $url = $this->_myHelper->getNoRoutePageUrl();
            header('Location: ' . $url);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

My event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\RedirectIp" name="namespace_module_observer_controller_actionpredispatch_controller_action_predispatch"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Should read more here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/magento-2-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-if-not-logged-in/131713#131713

Answer (score 0):

Below one you can follow

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class YourObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect) {
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), $this->redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is it doing or how I should implement this

Comment: Copy this code & put ur things in it Replace `$this->redirect->getRefererUrl()` with Ur URL which you want to redirect

Comment: I hope you understood my question. I am not asking how I should redirect. I am asking my redirection is going to infinite loop as the event get calls again and again. I tried your example and I am getting the same result

Comment: Try to remove ur condition & Check. Please also give Ur `events.xml` file as well

Comment: event xml added

Comment: Please give file location as well from magento root. U r observer is called on which event & when? Example `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`

Comment: hey bro. My event is working fine. I am just not able to get how I can stop the user if he wants to access the site from any page. So I want to redirect him to 404 CMS page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46781/discussion-between-ankit-shah-and-user3046689).

Answer (score 0):

set obeject :

```
//@var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect 
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
```

then just use setPath() method

```
return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
```