# Redirect if not logged in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

What logic uses magento 2 for checking user login in account page**s**? I know about solution like `$this->session->isLoggedIn()`, but I need more globally for several controllers. What I need to use?

Comment: You should take a look here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131713/33057

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
{
// your code
}
```