# Set Login page has store home page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, I need to redirect the store to login page when user enters the store address instead of homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Enterprise Version, we can do it easily by configuration: **STORES > Configuration > General > Website Restrictions**

But, for the Open source version, we need to implement our own logic.
We can see a simple example here: [Magento 2 - Redirect user to a specific page if not logged in](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/magento-2-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-if-not-logged-in/131713#131713)

Comment: I Don't perform any login operation. i just need to redirect from Home page to login page. Like if user enter store address, ex: localhost/magento2 instead of homepage, it should display login page (like setting the permission) without login, customer must not see the home page details.

Comment: yes, I think the link I gave you is your need.