# Redirect in observer http 500

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect

I am trying to redirect in my `controller_action_predispatch` observer. However, I got http 500 error, unable to handle the request

Note: I got the error 500 once i include `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http` (even if i don't do the redirect logic inside)

What could be the problem?

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Name\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RedirectObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $accountRedirect;
    protected $session;
    protected $url;
    protected $http;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect $accountRedirect,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http
    ) {
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->http = $http;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            // redirect to login page
            $this->http->setRedirect($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'), 301);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131713/33057

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try with

```
 <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface" type="Magento\Store\App\Response\Redirect" />
```

`Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface` or `Magento\Store\App\Response\Redirect`. A good example [Magento 2 - Redirect user to a specific page if not logged in](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131706/magento-2-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-if-not-logged-in/131713#131713)

Comment: I tried the sample given with `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface` on controller action predispatch observe but not working. still http error 500. Should i add the preference for it to work? Where should i add the preference in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the link I gave you it will work. Please, check other parts.

Comment: No, I just show you the preference. Don't to do anything with it.

Comment: It works after i remove all the var/pub folder and static deploy again. Do i have to do it all the time? I am in developer mode.

Comment: Don't need to do static deploy every time in developer mode. Just delete `pub/static`, not delete `.htaccess`. And then refresh the page again. The static content will be generated on fly and symlink.