# Show login page instead of homepage

Tags: magento2.3, login, home-page

I want to change default home page to login page in **Magento 2.3**

Mean that want to see customer login instead of homepage

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131713/72911)

> Create Event **controller_action_predispatch**, we can follow:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
 <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="check_login_persistent" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckLoginPersistentObserver" />
 </event>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CheckLoginPersistentObserver.php**

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;

    /**
     * Customer session
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect

    ) {

        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

        $openActions = array(
            'create',
            'createpost',
            'login',
            'loginpost',
            'logoutsuccess',
            'forgotpassword',
            'forgotpasswordpost',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'confirm',
            'confirmation'
        );
        if ($controller == 'account' && in_array($actionName, $openActions)) {
            return $this; //if in allowed actions do nothing.
        }
        if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'customer/account/login');
        }

    }
```